# Runnable JAR with duplicate dependencies

Tags: java, jar, dependencies, executable-jar

I am trying to create a runnable JAR using Eclipse, but an running into problems. The Eclipse workspace contains two separate projects which depend on the same library. I can create the runnable JAR, but the problem is when I run it I receive a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` exception.

I believe I'm receiving the `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` exception because the [libraries are different versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048779/when-do-we-get-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-even-when-the-jar-class-has-the-partic). Is there a common solution to fix this problem? If not, what would you recommend I do?

Comment: I understand that you mean "depend on different versions of the same library"?

Comment: Yes, project **A** depends on _lib-1.0_ and project **B** depends on _lib-2.0_. Also, project **A** depends on project **B**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the major version number changes it means that backwards compatibility may have changed.

You could try with the latest version and hope that they just did add methods and that the old way of working, but even if NoSuchMethod exception is not thrown there is no guarantee (maybe with the new API you should call differente methods to get the same results).

I would contact the provider of the library and ask them if compatibility is broken. If they do not answer or it is broken, and you have the source code, the only possibility would be refactoring one of the libraries (probably 1.0); v.g. putting all of it in new packet v1. Then you would have to change the project that depends of it.

If none of the above works, then the solution would be an OSGi container or to setup project A and project B as two different executables and setup project B as a server that answer project A messages. Messy

Comment: Thanks. Just as a side note, _lib-1.0_ and _lib-2.0_ aren't the actual libraries; they are just examples. The major and minor version numbers have no significance in my case, but could be the case for others.

Comment: If the difference is in minor version number, then just by using the last number you should be safe (if the provider of the library did things as it should). If the difference was with a release number, usually it should not really matter which one you used (but the last one would be advised).

Comment: I ended up just updating my project **A** to use the _lib-2.0_ library. It did require me to refactor some of my code, but luckily it wasn't much. Luckily the changes I had to make were small, but if they were going to take up more time I probably would have looked more into OSGi. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to only include one version of the library which can satisfy both of the libraries that use it. If that's not possible, you'll have to find a different way of going about things such that you can eliminate the conflict. Options include:

1. Remove one or more of the uses from your code that are causing the NoSuchMethodError.
2. Modify the source of one or more of the libraries so they can happily coexist.
3. Use an OSGi container, which would allow you to have two versions of the same library in the same application.

Answer (score 0):

As SJuan stated, you could use OSGI to set it up correctly. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader#JAR_hell