# Not giving same class files

Tags: java, ant, build

i used an ant build file to create a jar for my project.After the classes i got from build was not the same as of the classes of jar file exporting from eclipse.
because of this the jar from build is not working.
Here is my build.xml file

```
 <javac destdir="${build.dir}" srcdir="${src.dir}" source="1.5" target="1.5" >
        <compilerarg value="-Xlint:unchecked"/>
        <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
 </javac>
```

Comment: what java version do you use when expporting n eclipse? can you post an error of what isnt working?

Comment: it using java 1.6 version.     
error is
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:   com.org.nms.common.LookAndFeel.getInstance()

Comment: Read about different causes of nosuchmethod: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048779/when-do-we-get-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-even-when-the-jar-class-has-the-parti

Comment: Thanks Aksel Willgert. I found that the classes after getting from ant build are using java 1.5. How can i solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set target version in your ant-script. Something like:

```
<javac destdir="${build.dir}" srcdir="${src.dir}" source="1.6" target="1.6" >
```