# Unable to load Configuration in Struts

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, struts2

I'm trying to implement STRUTS SPRING AND HIBERNATE INTEGRATION ON ONLINE EXAMINATION. while running the project in Eclipse Kepler using apache tomcat 7.0.42, it throws me the following error

```
**HTTP Status 404 - /OnlineExam/registration.jsp**
**Description:**The requested resource is not available.
```

In Console log, following things appear,

```
    SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/C:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps/iSAS/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:16:73
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/C:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps/iSAS/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:16:73
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:418)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: Error building results for action userRegistration in namespace  - action - file:/C:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps/iSAS/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:16:73
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:367)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:468)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:264)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:111)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: There is no result type defined for type 'tiles' mapped with name 'SUCCESS'.  Did you mean 'tiles'? - result - file:/C:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps/iSAS/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:17:40
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.buildResults(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:621)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:365)
    ... 21 more
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

    <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory" />
    <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">       
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"/>
        </result-types>

        <action name="userRegistration" method="{1}" class="userRegistration">
            <result name="SUCCESS" type="tiles">isas.user.registration</result>
            <result name="ERROR" type="tiles">isas.errorPage</result>
            <result name="input" type="tiles">isas.user.registration</result>
        </action>

    </package>
</struts>
```

Please Help me Friends. I don't know why that appears. Anyway thanks in Advance...!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Struts Spring & Hibernate integration in Online Examination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723800/struts-spring-hibernate-integration-in-online-examination)

Comment: But i'm having different error right now ..!!! @AndreaLigios

Comment: are you using struts2-spring plugin to integrate Spring with struts2?

Comment: No. But just now i added that jar file. But it throws me a different error as mentioned above in console log @UmeshAwasthi  (I have edited that console log Information just now)

Comment: have you seen `struts.xml:16:73` and it is unable to load your configuration, i validate your xml file

Comment: I don't understand what u r saying..!! Please tell me briefly Sir. I'm very new to this topics...!!! @UmeshAwasthi

Comment: @Prasanna then change the title! Make it reflecting the REAL problem, because you have three different questions with three different problems and exactly the same name -.-

Comment: I have changed the title my friend. @AndreaLigios

Comment: Actually this above error is rectified. This Error Occurs because of missing struts2-tiles-plugin-2.0.11.2 Anyway Thanks to all for helping me in this issue. @AndreaLigios

Comment: Actually this above error is rectified. This Error Occurs because of missing struts2-tiles-plugin-2.0.11.2 Anyway Thanks to all for helping me in this issue. @UmeshAwasthi

Comment: Be aware that randomly mixing Struts 2 plugin versions will almost certainly cause problems at some point. And that you're using the Struts 2.0 DTD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the "struts2-spring-plugin-2.1.6.jar" file, please check it in your classpath

Comment: Thank u Sir @Ha Nguyen But now i'm getting different error as mentioned above in console log...!!!

Comment: Actually this above error is rectified. This Error Occurs because of missing struts2-tiles-plugin-2.0.11.2  Anyway Thanks to all for helping me in this issue.

Comment: Did you create a tiles.xml file in the folder WEB-INF?

If not, create it with contain below:

`code` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="baseLayout" template="/BaseLayout.jsp">
<put-attribute name="title" value="" />
<put-attribute name="header" value="/Header.jsp" />
<put-attribute name="body" value="" />
<put-attribute name="footer" value="/Footer.jsp" />
</definition>
</tiles-definitions>

Answer (score 1):

i got the same error, however , adding that jar did not fix my problem.

as the error states: `Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/C:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps/iSAS/WEB-INF/classes/`**struts.xml:16:73**

there is a problem in your struts.xml at line 16, which is

`<action name="userRegistration"` **method="{1}"** `class="userRegistration">`

struts tries to load the method named {1} from the class userRegistration. probably that method does not exist, as it is an invalid java name. i am not sure if struts accepts such a notation like {1} to refer to the first method in a class (probably not), but in my case, that was the problem: in struts.xml, in the action tag, i was refering a method whose name was misspelled, so struts was trying to find a nonexistent method, which caused this error - unable to load configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Have fixed the problem. Hope the solution would be useful for some one else:

struts.xml file must be present under WebContent - WEB-INF - classes - struts.xml when using eclipse

The mistake i did was when ever i did a clean project it used to delete my files under classes folder, so do make sure that this particular file is present.